# Spring exception parsing camel-config.xml in ServiceMix

Tags: spring, osgi, restlet, apache-servicemix

I got the following exception when trying to install and start a project in ServiceMix. This project runs correctly outside of ServiceMix using `mvn jetty:run`. So I know it is not the problem of the xml itself. But I don't know what the problem is. 
Could someone tell me what this error mean and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
13:16:23,983 | ERROR | l Console Thread | ContextLoader                    | 114 - org.springframework.web - 3.0.6.RELEASE | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [camel-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)[114:org.springframework.web:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)[114:org.springframework.web:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)[65:org.springframework.context:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)[65:org.springframework.context:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)[65:org.springframework.context:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)[114:org.springframework.web:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)[114:org.springframework.web:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)[114:org.springframework.web:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$1.call(HttpServiceContext.java:168)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$1.call(HttpServiceContext.java:164)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.addEventListener(HttpServiceContext.java:161)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl.addEventListener(JettyServerImpl.java:242)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Started.addEventListener(ServerControllerImpl.java:276)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl.addEventListener(ServerControllerImpl.java:127)[111:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerEventListener(HttpServiceStarted.java:286)[113:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.registerEventListener(HttpServiceProxy.java:133)[113:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:276)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:561)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:170)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:155)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:119)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.setService(ReplaceableService.java:114)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.access$100(ReplaceableService.java:28)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService$CollectionListener.serviceAdded(ReplaceableService.java:183)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection$Tracker.addingService(ServiceCollection.java:181)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)[karaf.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection.onStart(ServiceCollection.java:139)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.onStart(ReplaceableService.java:146)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:81)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.doPublish(WebXmlObserver.java:304)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.addingEntries(WebXmlObserver.java:153)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.register(BundleWatcher.java:186)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.access$000(BundleWatcher.java:45)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher$1.bundleChanged(BundleWatcher.java:127)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3761)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1787)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:918)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:905)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.InstallBundle.doExecute(InstallBundle.java:55)[19:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:218)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)[:1.6.0_18]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:126)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1333)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1328)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)[66:org.springframework.beans:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: I dont know much abt ServiceMix but have you checked the version of Maven it is using? Typically if you can something from command prompt without problems, then might be an issue with version of Maven

Comment: Do you need to use a proxy to connect to the internet? Cause this usually gives you such strange messages with spring